# Lumen returns MethodNotAllowedHTTPException only when request includes headers

Tags: reactjs, axios, lumen

I am using a combination of React, axios, and Lumen for my project and for some reason, when I try and include headers in my request, I get the error "MethodNotAllowedHTTPException ." I have a middleware in Lumen that checks if the api_token is valid, and if so, allows the program to run, but this error pops up regardless of if the middleware is active or not. This error only shows up if I have headers active in axios, if not, then it processes everything like normal. Here is what I have so far:

In React program:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'bearer 1234567890'}
});


 getService = (name, returnFunction) =>{
        instance.get('/service', {
            params:{
                name
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            returnFunction(response);
        }).catch( () =>{
            //TODO add error function
        })
    }
```

If I comment out the headers section, this code runs without issue and returns the expected data (assuming that I have the middleware in Lumen disabled of course). I have also tried running this same url in Postman with the Authorization header exactly as shown here, and it worked without issue, so I am lost as to what could be causing this problem.